# Quickest way to delete a folder including all files and subdirs

Tags: file-io, vb6, directory, delete-file

I would like to know if somebody knows which function is the fastest way to delete a folder and all its files and subdirectories.

I know (fastest one so far):

```
Dim SHFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT

With SHFileOp
    ' Function:  Delete
    .wFunc = FO_DELETE
    ' Which file/dir
    .pFrom = uFolder 
    ' Set flags
    .fFlags = FOF_SILENT Or _
              FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS Or _
              FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
End With

' Kiss it goodbye
SHFileOperation SHFileOp
```

and (much slower):

```
Dim fso
Dim fs

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fs = fso.DeleteFolder(uFolder, True)
```

Does anybody know a function that is even faster than the first?

Comment: Why is the process too slow for you?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the actual delete process that is tying up your active thread then you could try multi-threading the process.

Retain your fastest method above but get it to run in a parallel thread.